# How can I get GitHub pages to give a correct SSL certificate for my www subdomain

Tags: github-pages

https://joshuafox.com shows correctly. However, https://www.joshuafox.com gives an SSL certificate error.

The DNS records seem correct, as shown by `dig`, and by the fact that http://www.joshuafox.com (no HTTPS) correctly redirects.

```
$ dig www.joshuafox.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.joshuafox.com.  86400   IN  CNAME   joshuafox.com.
joshuafox.com.      3600    IN  A   185.199.109.153
```

[This new feature](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-08-github-pages-can-now-automatically-secure-the-www-variant-of-your-custom-domain/) in GitHub Pages is said to  support that. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Overhaul of the answer

To include your the `www` `apex`, you should add this line to the domain DNS record:

`CNAME www.joshuafox.com joshuafox.github.io 86400`

If you use `dig` it should look like:

```
dig www.joshuafox.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
;www.joshuafox.com.             IN      A
www.joshuafox.com.      86400   IN      CNAME   joshuafox.github.io.
joshuafox.github.io.    3600    IN      A       185.199.109.153
joshuafox.github.io.    3600    IN      A       185.199.110.153
joshuafox.github.io.    3600    IN      A       185.199.111.153
joshuafox.github.io.    3600    IN      A       185.199.108.153
```

```
dig joshuafox.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
;joshuafox.com.                 IN      A
joshuafox.com.          3600    IN      A       185.199.110.153
joshuafox.com.          3600    IN      A       185.199.111.153
joshuafox.com.          3600    IN      A       185.199.108.153
joshuafox.com.          3600    IN      A       185.199.109.153
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing the CNAME to point www to joshuafox.github.io seems correct. Also: I checked, and the A records are already there. But are you saying I should add another CNAME pointing joshuafox.github.io to GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER followed by space and a period. Why the space before the period? Is GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER meant as a placeholder? And also, are you saying there should be an A record from GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER followed by space and a period to 192.0.2.1, and if so -- what is the meaning of the 192.0.2.1?

Comment: It is now working. The relevant answer was just changing the CNAME to point www to joshuafox.github.io . The other CNAMES and first A was not needed and the last 4 As were already there.

Comment: @JoshuaFox You are welcome. I'm glad you got it working.  I'll edit the answer to answer your questions.  In short `GITHUB-PAGES-SERVER` is a placeholder, in your case `joshuafox.com` and `192.0.2.1` is also an IPv4 address placeholder, this IPv4 is reserved for test networks (it is also called a Bogon), - should be replaced by the github IPv4.

Comment: Thank you; But it seems that most of these zones are irrelevant (and should be removed from the answer). I do not have them and my setup now works,

Comment: @JoshuaFox Now I'm lost.  Which zones are irrelevant? (I'll gladly remove them)  Your setup works as you have alias `www.joshuafox.com` to `joshuafox.github.io.` which then has Address mapping record (`A`) record to github IP.  While `joshuafox.com.` has direct Address mapping.  If you would use one `CNAME` you would get the same reply for both.

Comment: My current DNS as shown by dig, is   https://gist.github.com/JoshuaFox/5b4af62e07dd170231ffd7a632ad48e8 So, any zones that are not in the DNS setup are clearly unnecessary

Comment: @JoshuaFox Ah, I understand now (I tried it on my own domain) where my misunderstanding is. I thought you have your own DNS server configured not your web hosting one. I'll fix it. Thank you for your patience :).